# Android stop tasks in doInbackGround and return to postExecute

Tags: android, android-asynctask

i'm sorry for asking too many questions this days, but i really need ur help to finish this app. 
In my `doInBackground` (asynctask) :
   A loop that parses some feeds and fills a list with results.
In my `onPostExecute` :
   the result list constructed above is sended to ListAdapter to display results.

Is it a way to interrupt the loop in the doInBackground (while displaying the progress dialog)
and return the list to the onPostExecute ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a way to interrupt the loop in the `doInBackground` and then execute the `onCancelled`. You should check cancellation status in the `doInBackground` using `isCancelled`.

Comment: thanks, 'onCancelled' solves the prob, so i put the same code from the 'onPostExecute' and i got the expected result.